# Not working Object.create(Error.prototype)

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, frontend

i have code:

```
var TestError = function () {
var that = Error.call(this);
return that;
};
TestError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
TestError.prototype.why = function(){alert("NOT WORKING")}

var err = new TestError();
err.why();//not working :( TypeError: err.why is not a function
```

but not working :(

When I write

```
var TestError = function () {
var that = Error.call(this);
return that;
};
TestError.prototype = Error.prototype;
TestError.prototype.why = function(){alert("WORKING")}

var err = new TestError();
err.why();// working :(
```

Why i cant use Object.create(Error.prototype)?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not with `Object.create`. The problem is that you `return that;` from the constructor.

`that` is an instance of `Error`, not of `TestError`. So when you *correctly* add `why` to `TestError.prototype`, only instances of `TestError` will have that method, not `Error`.

This is roughly the state of the environment in your first example:

```
+--------------------+       +------------------------+        +-----------------+
|     TestError      |       |  TestError.prototype   | +----->| Error.prototype |
+------------+-------+       +-------------+----------+ |      +-----------------+
|  prototype |   *---+------>|     why     |<Function>| |               ^         
+------------+-------+       +-------------+----------+ |               |         
                             |[[Prototype]]|      *---+-+               |         
                             +-------------+----------+                 |         
                                                                        |         
                                                                        |         
                             +------------------------+                 |         
+--------------------+       |        <Object>        |                 |         
|        err         |------>+-------------+----------+                 |         
+--------------------+       |[[Prototype]]|     *----+-----------------+         
                             +-------------+----------+
```

Remove the line `return that;` and it will work.

```js
var TestError = function() {
  Error.call(this);
};
TestError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
TestError.prototype.why = function() {
  alert("WORKING")
}

var err = new TestError();
err.why();
```

Because this is what you want:

```
+--------------------+       +------------------------+        +-----------------+
|     TestError      |       |  TestError.prototype   | +----->| Error.prototype |
+------------+-------+       +-------------+----------+ |      +-----------------+
|  prototype |   *---+------>|     why     |<Function>| |                         
+------------+-------+       +-------------+----------+ |                         
                             |[[Prototype]]|      *---+-+                         
                             +-------------+----------+                           
                                          ^                                       
                                          |                                       
                                          +---------------+                       
                                                          |                       
                             +------------------------+   |                       
+--------------------+       |        <Object>        |   |                       
|        err         |------>+-------------+----------+   |                       
+--------------------+       |[[Prototype]]|     *----+---+                       
                             +-------------+----------+
```

---

Why does it work without `Object.create` ? Because when you do

```
TestError.prototype = Error.prototype;
```

every extension you make to `TestError.prototype` extends `Error.prototype`. So when you add `why`, every instance of `Error` will have that method.

As I mentioned above, `return that;` returns an instance of `Error`. Since all error instances now have a `why` method, that works, but rather by accident, not by intentionally.

```
+--------------------+                                                 
|     TestError      |                       +------------------------+
+------------+-------+                       |    Error.prototype     |
|  prototype |   *---+---------------------->+-------------+----------+
+------------+-------+                       |     why     |<Function>|
                                             +-------------+----------+
                                                          ^            
                                                          |            
                                                          |            
                             +------------------------+   |            
+--------------------+       |        <Object>        |   |            
|        err         |------>+-------------+----------+   |            
+--------------------+       |[[Prototype]]|     *----+---+            
                             +-------------+----------+
```

```js
var TestError = function () {
var that = Error.call(this);
   return that;
};
TestError.prototype = Error.prototype;
TestError.prototype.why = function(){alert("WORKING")}

var err = new Error(); // <- Note that we execute Error here
err.why();// working, but it shouldn't. Every Error instance now has a why method
```

Comment: but, why I have in TestError.prototype object two property. One my custom property and "stock" property. Custom property i know why is there but i dont know why in TestError.prototype is stock property.can you tell me?

Comment: Every object has an internal `[[Prototype]]` property which points to the prototype of the object.

Comment: I know that. But when i run console.log(TestError.prototype) i get in property "stock". Why?

Comment: Are you saying you literally have a property `stock`? I don't know where that comes from.

Comment: run console.log(TestError.prototype). When do this, you will get show that stock is in TestError.prototype. WHy?

Comment: Can't repro: https://jsfiddle.net/ohf5y56a/ . It must have something to do with your specific environment. Not much I can do here and also not relevant to this question.

Comment: run console.log(TestError.prototype) and you get: Object { why: TestError.prototype.why(), stack: "" }

Comment: i tested on file:/// on firefox 49

Comment: @MankamentGra: The property is called st**a**ck, not st**o**ck! It's non-standard property in Firefox, as you can [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack). It's not a property defined on `TestError.prototype`, it's inherited from `Error.prototype`. Use `console.dir(TestError.prototoype)` instead of `console.log` to get a better idea of the structure of the object.